# What about a material makes it diamagnetic

Tags: electromagnetism

For a material to be magnetic, all the magnetic atoms (atoms with half filled electron shells) need to be aligned, but what about a material gives it the property of diamagnetism?

Answer (score 0):

There are several mechanisms causing diamagnetism. And *all* atoms are diamagnetic to a certain degree, this property may only be hidden by paramagnetism.

The fundamental mechanism driving diamagetism is (very roughly) Lenz's law, that an induced current lowers the inbound field.

The atom's diamagnetism is driven by the $\propto \vec A^2$-term in the Hamiltonian of an electron coupled to the electromagnetic field (this can be found in any introductory book on QM).

Superconductors are perfect diamagnets up to a critical field strength.

Conductors are AC diamagnets (as can be seen in the typical introductory course experiment of an aluminium ring repelled by a solenoid which is driven by AC).